# What type of visa should I get to participate in startup programs in Germany?

Tags: visa, germany, startups

I am from Asia and want to participate in startup programs in Germany<sup>*</sup>. What type of visa should I get? I also like to know if my proposal is accepted in an accelerator/incubator, what kind of visa do I need?

If I want to create a new startup/company in Germany, are there startup/entrepreneurship visa for that? Where can I read the requirements and apply for that? What is the Germany government website that I can use?

<sup>* E.g. programs like what this institute provides: https://www.joinef.com/. These kinds of programs take 3 to 12 months with different institutes</sup>